# Save and resize image to Cloudinary without saving image on disk

Tags: node.js, azure, cloudinary

How can I resize multiple images and send stream to [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) directly by using mutiparty:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.on('part', function(part) {
       // Stream it to Cloudinary without saving it to disk
    }
}
```

I do this because I am hosting in the Azure website, there is no way to save the image in the temp folder.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about that bu you can try:

```
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary'); //npm install cloudinary
cloudinary.config({/*your config object*/});
var request = require('request'); //npm install request

router.post('/', function(req, res){
    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.on('part', function(part) {
        if (part.filename) {
            var url = cloudinary.url(part.filename, {type: 'fetch'/*, width: 256*/});
            request.head(url, function (err, res, body) {
                //...
            });
        }
    }
}
```